# How to insert a chart/table in powerpoint through office.js add-in

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I plan to create a powerpoint add-in which will auto init a ppt with data in database. How can I insert/update a chart/table into a slide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OfficeJS APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/powerpoint-add-ins-reference-overview). For example, the following function uses the Office JavaScript API to insert the image into the document. Note:

- The `coercionType` option that's specified as the second parameter of the `setSelectedDataAsync` request indicates the type of data being inserted.
- The `asyncResult` object encapsulates the result of the `setSelectedDataAsync` request, including status and error information if the request failed.

```
function insertImageFromBase64String(image) {
    // Call Office.js to insert the image into the document.
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(image, {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image
    },
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                showNotification("Error", asyncResult.error.message);
            }
        });
}
```

You can read more about that in the [Tutorial: Create a PowerPoint task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Neither the Office.js API or PowerPoint JavaScript API currently support adding a table into PowerPoint, you can only do this in Word and Excel at the moment, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-javascript-api-object-model).  A possible workaround could be to produce a table in a temporary ppt file using something like [PptxGenJS](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/html-to-powerpoint/), and then using the [PowerPoint JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/insert-slides-into-presentation) to copy the slide with the table from the temporary ppt to the ppt that the addin is running in.

Answer (score 0):

To add content in PowerPoint, use the Commond APIs of Office JavaScript. Start with [Common JavaScript API object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-javascript-api-object-model).

Answer (score 0):

From other answers you might already know that the Charts/Tables/Shapes cannot be inserted in PowerPoint using the Office.js API, Using *@Eugene Astafiev*'s answer works but the charts are still images and you cannot customize them.

Since the Office.js AddIns work on the browsers and the Office API let's you insert existing slides to the presentation from other presentations, you can use any javascript library that provide Open Office Xml presentation generation. In my case, I have used the [PPTXGenJS](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS) library.

First I have created a presentation with Slides containing Charts/Tables/Shapes, Then I converted the presentation object to base64 format. It can then be inserted to the active presentation using the Office.js API.

```
var pres = new PptxGenJS();
  var slide = pres.addSlide();
  slide.addTable(['Color', 'Value'], ['Red', 1], ['Blue', 2]);
  pres.write('base64').then(async function (data) {
    await PowerPoint.run(async function (context) {
     // Used to read the slide which is selected by the user so that we can preserve the destination format in the presentation, the method can be found in the Microsoft Script Lab samples
      const selectedSlideID = await getSelectedSlideID();
      context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(data, { formatting: PowerPoint.InsertSlideFormatting.useDestinationTheme, targetSlideId: selectedSlideID + "#" });
      await context.sync();
    });

  });
```

Comment: Can we update chart/table dynamic data after first render?

Comment: You are inserting it as slide. With this method, you have to recreate the slide with the chart, delete the old slide and insert it in it's place. Any change that was done to the chart will be lost. But until Microsoft release an update for the Office JS API, this is the only way.

Comment: @insomniac "any change done to the chart will be lost" what do you mean by that, I am trying to assess if I can use powepoint as a frontend for backend api and exchange information, create update slides and shapes